# Strange behavior in React hook state updates in combination with setInterval()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

The below code correctly updates the count state, but when outputting the count value with console.log, it is showing very strange behavior if called from a function within an setInterval inside useEffect() hook.

You would expect to see an incremental number in the console.log but the output from the fetchTimelineItems() function is bizar. When the count is 1, the output alternates between 0 and 1. When the count is 2 or more it outputs all the numbers in random order.

See codesandbox link to reproduce this behavior.

The expected behavior is to see the correct count value in the fetchTimelineItems() function.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction to get this fixed.

```js
const Example = ({ title }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

  function fetchTimelineItems() {
    console.log("count from within fetch function: " + count);
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      fetchTimelineItems();
    }, 3000)
  },[count]);

  

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{title}</p>
      <button onClick={handleCount}>Increase count</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/count-update-s5z94?file=/src/index.js

Comment: You are setting multiple timeouts. Use effect runs on mounting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` hooks, runs after `mounting` and `updating` (depending on your dependency array) of your functional component.

So, it keeps running whenever you update your `count`.

Now, once you update `count` for the first time, the `useEffect` will again run, thus creating a new `Interval` because of `setInterval`. This is why you have multiple output statement.

Now, finally, each `Interval` you create is creating what is called a `closure` inside it. Inside this `closure` there is the `fetchTimelineItems` function along the value of `count` at that point of time.

So, for every update of `count` you are creating new intervals like this.

Mount -> Closure with `fetchTimelineItems` and `count` = 0,
Update count once -> Closure with `fetchTimelineItems` and `count` = 1,
Update count again -> Closure with `fetchTimelineItems` and `count` = 2,

This is why you have all the values printing in the console.
Why it is printing old values is because that's how `closures` work in javascript. They remember the values at the time of their creation.

Comment: so how should we do it? considering simple number update   const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      setNumber(number + 1);
    }, 500);
  }
  , [number]);

  return <div>{number}</div>